# Why do we need the commutative axiom of multiplication?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, axioms, fake-proofs

I think I can prove that $ab = ba$ by other axioms.  Am I wrong?  Why?

***Edit:** proof updated with notes showing where I actually used the commutative property without noticing.*

*Proof.*  For any numbers $a$ and $b$, we know this is true:
$$
ab + ab = ab + ab
$$

By using the distribution axiom:
$$\begin{split}
a(b + b) &= \underbrace{b(a + a)}_{\text{mistake: implies commutivity}}\\
a(2b) &= b(2a)\\
a2b &= b2a\\
\end{split}$$

By multiplying both sides by $2^{-1}$:
$$\begin{split}
a2b2^{-1} &= b2a2^{-1}\\
\end{split}$$

By the multiplication associative axiom:
$$\begin{split}
ab(22^{-1}) &= ba(22^{-1}) \qquad\text{(mistake: requires commutivity)}\\
\end{split}$$

By the multiplication inverse axiom:
$$\begin{split}
ab(1) &= ba(1)\\
\end{split}$$

By the multiplication identity axiom:
$$ab = ba$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: At your first step, I got $a(b+b)=(a+a)b$, not $b(a+a)$.

Comment: "By the multiplication associative axiom: "  Um  ... $a2b2^{-1} = ab(22^{-1})$ doesn't follow by associativity.  It *require* commutivity to make the claim.

Comment: Oh and as Lord Shark points out you can say $ab+ab=(a+a)b$ but you can *not* say $ab+ab = b(a+a)$ unless you assume commutivity in the first place.

Comment: Lord Shark makes a valid point, though doing that step properly still gets you to $2ab$, and you still need to swap $2$ and $a$ in order to get to what the other side gives which is $a2b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.  If you don't have commutativity we can't claim $b(a+a) = (a+a)b,$ and so distribution would allow only $ab +ab = (a+a)b= 2ab$ and you can't get $ab+ab =b(a+a)= b2a$.

Second you claim you can get $a2b2^{-1}= ab(22^{-1})$ from associativity.  I... just can't see any justification as to how associativity implies that, as the $b$ and the $2$ have "switched places"... I can't see any reason that could be without commutivity.

....

Interestingly though for all the "integers" -- terms that arise as $1+1 = 2$ and $2+1 = 3$, etc. -- you can claim limited commutativity as

$2b = (1+1)b = b+b = b(1+1) = b2$.

But I don't think you can extend that to elements that are not "rational".  (i.e., not a sum of $1$s or a sum of $1$ multiplied by an inverse of another sum of squares).  But I think you can prove by induction all "rationals" in a "non-commutative field" commute.

But I don't *think* a non-commutative field, in and of itself, is internally inconsistent. (I could be wrong.)

Comment: Did transition from $b+b$ to $b(1+1)$ imply commutivity?  E.g. I wonder if non-$1$ coefficients are usually written, but if not written, I wonder if they are implied to be a $1$ on the left side?  E.g. $1b+1b$ becomes only $(1+1)b$ in the next step?

Comment: No, because $b = 1*b = b*1$.  That's an axiom of the indentity.  Identities and inverses commute.  Now you can have rings that have *left* and *right* identities and *left* and *right* inverses that don't commute.  But if we assume all the field axioms *except* multiplicative commutivity,  We have $1$ commutes by axiom.

Comment: And if $1$ commutes, then $1+1$ and $1+1+1$ and $(1+2)^{-1}$ and $(1+1+1+1+1)*(1+1)^{-1}$ also commute.  But a "non-commutative field" without a general commutivity axiom, may have elements that can't be expressed in that way that don't commute.  I think.  ... So far as I know, there isn't much use or purpose in studying "non-commutative fields".

Comment: In your first line, I think you mean "we *can't* claim".

Comment: "In your first line, I think you mean "we can't claim".  It's been so long I can't tell *what* I meant but... yeah.  Leaving ought the "not" is a common for me typo (an infuriating one as it fumdamentally changes the mean, but irritatingly hard to proof as I pychologically just don't see it *because* it is so fundamental).  And this does make utterly no sense otherwise.

Comment: "s the b and the 2 have "switched places"... I can't see any reason that could be without *associativity*."  I'm going to have to assume I meant *commutivity*.

Answer (score 3):

The step you justified by associativity cannot be justified that way; it is actually a case of commutativity (you swapped the order of $2$ and $b$ on the left, and the order of $2$ and $a$ on the right).

Comment: You mean I performed 2 steps?  One swapping $2$ and $b$, and then associating them together into $(22^{-1})$?

Comment: @caveman You could think of it that way; associativity is so thoroughly baked into our notation that I tend not to think of invoking it as a "step".